# segmentation fault with pointer in for loop

Tags: c++

The code compiles fine and runs fine until the for loop to iterate through f_read_Prediction_Set. The segmentation fault occurs directly after that line...what am I missing?

```
std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >* transCoherence::getCurrentSets(uint32_t log2AddrLs, uint32_t maskSets, uint32_t log2Assoc, int pid, RAddr caddr)//function to return prediction set
{
   uint32_t set;
   std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >* currentSets = new std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >;
   std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >* f_read_Prediction_Set = new std::map< RAddr, uint32_t >;

   for(std::map<RAddr, uint32_t>::iterator it = f_read_Prediction_Set->begin(); it!=f_read_Prediction_Set->end(); ++it)
   {
      set = (((it->first) >> log2AddrLs) & maskSets) << log2Assoc;
      if(set == caddr)
         (*currentSets)[set] = 1;
   }

   return currentSets;
}
```

Comment: How can you iterate through an empty map?

Comment: @Beta - I was thinking that - Perhaps a demo on codepad would help

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I guess I walked right into that one.

Comment: @Beta lol yes quickly, originally that line of code initializing the new map wasnt there and it wasnt empty and i got the same fault...

Comment: You have a memory leak in that function.  Are you a former (or current) Java programmer, by any chance?

Comment: @JazzyBelle - If you're not aware of why I ask if you're a Java programmer, let me explain.  Usually it is (unwise) Java programmers (or programmers that use languages that have automatic garbage collection) that write C++ functions that use operator "new" in such a cavalier manner, unaware that C++ does not have the out-of-the-box garbage collection.  The reason for the crash is probably not that function you posted , but a corruption of the heap somewhere else in your program that causes that function to become erratic.  You avoid all this by writing code similar to the answer below.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh ok so if i use the new operator and it is called a lot I use up all of my memory?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that you're using all the memory. The point is simply that if you dynamically allocate memory with new, you need to delete it when you're done. If you delete something that wasn't allocated with new, or if you delete something multiple times, or if you delete something and try to use what's there, C++ can get very confused.

Comment: @KevinMills Thank you! I added some delete statements in parts of the code where it would be okay to delete the data structures and its running nicely now :)))

Answer (score 1):

Let me take your code full of pointers and dynamically allocation and translate it to an error and memory leak free version:

```
std::map<RAddr, uint32_t> transCoherence::getCurrentSets(uint32_t log2AddrLs, uint32_t maskSets, uint32_t log2Assoc, int pid, RAddr caddr) 
{
    std::map<RAddr, uint32_t> currentSets;
    std::map<RAddr, uint32_t> f_read_Prediction_Set;

    // populate f_read_Prediction_Set

    for (const auto& p : f_read_Prediction_Set) {
        uint32_t set = (((p.first >> log2AddrLs) & maskSets) << log2Assoc);
        if(set == caddr)
            currentSets[set] = 1;
    }

    return currentSets;
}
```

so that you can forget about the pointer problem entirely.

If you worried about *performance* you should note that there's a little thing in C++ called RVO (Return Value Optimization) that will avoid actually copying the vector back when the function returns.

Also I can't fail to notice that you use the word "set" in your map object's names, so it's good for you to know that there's an [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) class for you to use if you desire unique keys.

Comment: Heh, it looks much better now. But anyways it doesn't explain the segfault.

Comment: Now you just need to add some data to the `f_read_Prediction_Set` so that the returned map is not empty. :D

Comment: Thanks! does anyone know why that was happening though? My professor has guided me to use the pointers so I would like to be able to understand why my use of them is fail...also no im not a java programmer :p im not a programmer at all really im an EE with a thesis in computer arch, thanks for all the help :) (adds data to f_read_Prediction_Set)

Comment: @JazzyBelle, Well, your professor is wrong. Pointers are disappearing very fast from the C++ scene and in C++14 there's little use for them. When you use `new` you always have to pair it with a `delete`. In your code the first mistake is that you are not deleting `f_read_Prediction_Set` by the end of the function (effectively leaking its memory). The second mistake is that you are also returning the pointer of the other dynamically allocated map to the callee who does not know if he has to delete it or not (possibly leaking that too).

Comment: @JazzyBelle, as far as your segmentation goes: at first sight your code is fine. The segmentation fault might be happening somewhere else. But to be honest I've lost my patience with pointers months ago and I don't have the strength necessary to survive another pointer debugging (:P). The general rule of thumb is: never use naked pointers and if you really do use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and wrap them.

Comment: @JazzyBelle, Finally, please remember to read about *smart pointers*, `std::optional` and all the fancy new features of C++11 and C++14 once that course is finished and purify yourself from pointers entirely. You'll not only benefits a lot from that yourself but you'll also help the community finally grow away from them.